# Print values in relation to a fixed scale

Tags: python, printing

I have data in the following form.

```
Species1 277:A 352:B 423:C 566:D........10000:G
Species2 247:A 352:B 423:C 566:D........9500:G
Species3 271:A 349:B 566:C....7500:G
```

In each case, values before the colon ':' is the location. It ranges from 0 till 10,000. And value after the columns is some data I am interested in. I already know that no value exceeds 10,000. It means values can plotted on screen in relation to their location. In other words, we print for each species, values on screen on a fixed scale from 0-10,000. Values that are missing are not printed. Is it possible to get this kind of output on screen in print?
Output:

```
    Species1   A B C     D                           G
    Species2   A B C     D                         G
    Species3   A B       C                  G
```

So characters are printed according to their location. For example, G in species 1 is at 10,000. So it is printed at the end. G in species B is at 9500 so it is just to the left of G in species 1. So basically, I want values to be printed according to their location information.

Comment: Please give an example of what you want printed (perhaps for a smaller range of 0-10).

Comment: Just edited to show you the desired output.

Comment: What is format of your data? List, dic, set?

Comment: It is dict. Value to the left of the colon is the key and to the right is its value. But I have this information stored in a text file as well. And I can parse each line If I figure out how to control printing location of values.

Comment: With values 10000 and 247, you will need a log scale, No?

Comment: Multiply a space to the key, then add the value. Scaling based on the terminal size will avoid inconsistencies. `formatted = ''.join( [ str( ' ' * l[0] + l[1] ) for l in lst ] )`

Comment: @raymelfrancisco: values goes to 10 000. Yes? And for a given list, all values are on the same scale (B is at 352, not at 352+277).

Answer (score 1):

Well: a very crude solution using list of tuples

```
sp1=[(277, "A"), (352, "B"), (423, "C"), (566, "D")]
sp1.sort()
fact = 80/sp1[-1][0]
pos = 0
for elem in sp1:
    ch = " "*int(elem[0]*fact - pos) + elem[1]
    pos += len(ch)
    print(ch, sep="", end = "")
```

No?

Comment: Thanks. It is useful indeed. Gives me direction to fix the code. Just gives an error on my screen but I can take it from here I guess. Thanks so much for your input once more :)

Answer (score 1):

On the same way:

```
sp1=[(277, "A"), (352, "B"), (423, "C"), (566, "D")]
sp1.sort()
lst = [" "]*80
fact = 80/sp1[-1][0]
for elem in sp1:
    lst[int(elem[0]*fact-1)] = elem[1]

print("".join(lst))
```

Output:

```
                            A         B         C                    D
```

Comment: Thank you very much. On my screen it just prints 'D' to the far right. But it gives me direction to fix it. Much appreciated. Thanks again.